# Populate new column with values from database MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL query where I fetch with association a list of users' visits ordered by desc date.

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `date` 
FROM `logs` 
WHERE `iid` = ? 
ORDER BY `date` DESC';
```

Each log has `iid, id, name, date`, the generated array so has the 3 requested values for each row.

Here an example of the database:

```
| iid   | id    | name  | date              |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-13 10:14  |
| 2     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-12 08:10  |
| 2     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-11 14:43  |
| 1     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-10 15:12  |
```

`iid` is the page, `id` the user id.

Now I need to add a 4th column, called `lastvisit` which should contain the date of the previous visit by each user on each `iid`.
So I should have two different `lastvisit` values for the two `iid`:

```
| iid   | id    | name  | date              | lastvisit         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-13 10:14  | 2013-09-12 15:12  |
| 2     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-12 08:10  | 2013-09-11 14:43  |
| 2     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-11 14:43  | null              |
| 1     | 1     | foo   | 2013-09-10 15:12  | null              |
```

I will add this column to the database and at each visit I will check the most recent visit to get the `lastvisit` value to put in the new entry.

My problem is about the already recored entries, which have not the value for `lastvisit`.

I need to populate them with a query, something like:

```
UPDATE `logs`
SET `lastvisit` = (
    SELECT `date`
    FROM `logs` 
    WHERE `id` = ? AND 'iid' = ?
    ORDER BY `date` DESC'
    LIMIT 0, 1;
)
```

Obviosly this query doesn't work, is it possible to write a query to perform this task for each entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close.  You need a correlated subquery to connect the inner query to the outer table being updated.  I think this will work:

```
UPDATE `logs` l
    SET `lastvisit` = (
        SELECT `date`
        FROM `logs` l2
        WHERE l2.id = l.id AND l2.iid = l.iid AND l2.date <= l.date
        ORDER BY `date` DESC'
        LIMIT 0, 1;
    );
```

Actually, I think MySQL has a problem with subqueries that use the update table (arrggg).  You can phrase this as the more complicated:

```
update logs l join
       (select l.*,
               if(@id = id and @iid = iid, @date, NULL) as prevdate,
               @id := id, @iid := iid, @date := date
        from logs l cross join
             (select @date := '', @id := '', @iid := '') const
        order by id, iid, date
       ) lprev
       on l.id = lprev.id and l.iid = lprev.iid and l.date = lprev.date
    set l.lastvisit = lprev.prevdate;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try when I've access to the DB, but may you explain me how it works? What are `l`, `l2` etc?

Comment: It tells: `Every derived table must have its own alias` and by the way `prevdate` should be `lastvisit`?

Comment: Both problems are fixed.  In fact, it is `l.date` that should be `l.lastvisit`.

Comment: Thanks, no errors but the entire column is now populated with a single date, the same for all the entries... (the date is the current time)

Comment: @FezVrasta . . . There were two typos in the answer, but I don't think they would cause that problem.  Does the subquery return the correct previous date? . . . Never mind.  I think the problem is that `@iid` was being set to `id` and not `iid`.